# Parsing or filtering specific sections from a text file using javascript

Tags: javascript

Currently...button click returns everything from the text file t/hello.txt to the div.

Looking to see if there is a way to return the whole text file then parse out specific data and return it to the div. In the example below I would like to return everything bewteen Section 1 to the div just the way it looks.

Example - data is set up like the following in the text file:

```
Section1
Type: Cat
Name: Whiskers
Age: 2 yrs
Status: Adoption
Section1

Section2
Type: Dog
Name: Rosco
Age: 7 yrs
Status: Adoption
Section2


<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
var tdata ;
if(navigator.appName.search('Microsoft')>-1) { tdata = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP'); }
else { tdata = new XMLHttpRequest(); }

function seetxt() {
tdata.open('get', 't/hello.txt', true); 
tdata.onreadystatechange= cp;
tdata.send(null);
}

function cp() {
if(tdata.readyState==4) {
var ele = document.getElementById('ctxt');
ele.innerHTML = tdata.responseText;
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="See Values"  onclick="seetxt()">
<div id="ctxt"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

added the following based on @levi suggestion...nothing appeared on button click

```
function cp() {
if(tdata.readyState==4) {
var ele = document.getElementById('ctxt');
var txt = tdata.responseText.match(/Section1(.+?)Section1/i)[1];
ele.innerHTML = txt;
//ele.innerHTML = tdata.responseText;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format of your text file is like your example, you can use the following regex to extract a sections contents:

```
var txt = tdata.responseText.match(/section1(.+?)section1/i)[1];
ele.innerHTML = txt;
```

Comment: levi I added what you said and on button click nothing showed up. Data is formatted like my example

Comment: Might be an error in your code, check the console. Code should work fine. see - http://jsfiddle.net/8uRJ6/

Comment: levi - when running it as you suggested I get a uncaught type error: can not read property '1' of null txtFile onreadystatechange on this line var txt = tdata.responseText.match(/section1(.+?)section1/i)[1];

Comment: what I did do to get it to work is I put each section on a single line like: Section1 Type: Cat Name: Whiskers Age: 2 yrs Status: Adoption Section1 then changed (/section1(.+?)section1/i) to (/section1 (.+?) section1/i) then it worked.